# How to map Windows Ctrl to Win only when remoted into a Mac

Tags: windows-10, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, teamviewer

I use TeamViewer to remote from a Windows 10 PC to a MacBookPro (running Catalina up to Monterey). I have a Logitech wireless keyboard attached to the Mac (via Unifying USB). I want to be able to map Ctrl to Win and Win to Ctrl. Nothing fancy. I have tried both PowerToys and Karibiner with these results:
PowerToys maps Ctrl-C, etc just fine, but I cannot map Win back to Ctrl, so I can never stop a running process in my Terminal app, ie ctrl-c; can't save nor exit in Nano and the iTerm2 Toolbelt doesn't work with Nano.

Karabiner Elements simply doesn't work. I have tried everything. I have disabled PowerToys, made sure I don't have any Modifier Keys mapped. It simply does not work, as in nothing happens, despite the MacOS Virtual Keyboard showing me pressing the Ctrl key, Karabiner just won't recognize it.

Edit: PowerToys, TeamViewer, Karabiner and MacOS Key Modifiers can all be used simultaneously or in separate combinations and I have tried all of the combinations that are possible and nothing seems to work swapping both Ctrl to Win and Win to Ctrl. Many of the combinations work mapping Ctrl to Win, but not Win to Ctrl.

I am sending Key Combinations in TeamViewer and I have contacted their tech support about this. They claim is working as expected and I can request a new feature...which I did...two years ago. I check on it periodically and they tell me to pound sand.

Comment: I can't quite tell what the issue is here. You start by talking about TeamViewer from Win to Mac, but then you swap to trying to change the Mac keyboard input from inside the Mac itself. Which of these do you need, because changing what the local keyboard sends to the Mac will not change what your remote keyboard sends to it. On the Mac itself you can change the modifier keys directly from the keyboard control panel, no 3rd party required at all. Sending from Win over TeamViewer is an entirely different matter.

Comment: @Tetsujin All the settings interplay (ie TeamViewer and internal Mac Keyboard). I was trying to be descriptive. I have tried using just MacOS key modification with TeamViewer and it does not work. That's why I then tried Karabiner...then tried PowerToys and every combination of the three. Nothing seems to work as desired.

Comment: Reading on my phone. When I get to computer, I can post a pair of `.eg` files, one to remap and one to restore default. IIRC, the OS requires a reboot for the change to take effect -- is that acceptable or a deal-breaker?

Comment: @KeithMiller That sounds like keys being mapped on Windows for all apps until the next reboot. I don't think that will work, because I only need them mapped while TeamViewer is in the foreground as I typically use both the PC and the Mac to accomplish a single task/project.

Comment: You don't have left and right `ctrl` *and* `Win` keys, do you? You could remap one set and leave the other alone it might take some getting used to..

Comment: @KeithMiller not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

**AutoHotkey** should do the trick. For example to swap the `Ctrl` and `Win` keys on the left only in *Notepad* you do this:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad
LWin::LCtrl
LCtrl::LWin
return
```